# Indexing and table relationships for sql database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'd really appreciate some advice on how to setup my table design and what type of indexing I should use.

I figured this type of requirement has come up alot before so hopefully I could benefit from your advice!

The requirement, and my initial plan is as follows:

I have one table which identifies a limited amount of forms

```
FormID FormName Desc etc..
```

I will have a second table that populates information for those forms.
(EquipmentIds are unique. So a piece of equipment may require one of the forms from the previous table.)

```
ID  FormID  EquipmentID  Element       Value 
-----------------------------------------------------
 1   25     3432         lightswitch   GE Lightbulb
 2   25     3432         lamp          nice lamp
 3   25     3432         rug           really ties the room together
 4   25     3432         shelf         good shelf
 5   25     3432         ...           ....
 6   23     2314         ...           ....
```

So essentially all of the information for the forms would be in the second table. To populate a form I would then select from form filler on the FormID AND EquipmentID.

Is there a better way of doing this? It makes sense to me but I could see the table growing very quickly and I am wondering what the best way to index this second table would be.

Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing with this data? I question if Mr Karwin's assessment of what you are doing is accurate. So you have multiple "elements" per form. What do you do with these? What does it mean? Perhaps you can give a more complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are implementing a variation on the [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-attribute-value) design. I have written several times that this is not a valid design for a *relational* database.

- You lose the ability to use SQL data types appropriately.
- You lose the ability to use SQL constraints like UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY, and even NOT NULL.
- Queries against EAV data don't scale well.
- The storage is bulky and inefficient. Not only does it create many rows, but the first three columns have a lot of duplication in values, making indexes less efficient.
- To use EAV data, you have to write lots more application code to check data types, simulate constraints, and reformat result sets. This is extra work that the RDBMS already does for you more efficiently.

The correct design for a relational database is to design a table for each of your forms, with form fields in distinct columns, so you can choose the column names, data types, constraints appropriately. Form fields that allow multiple values require separate child tables too.